# Angular 1/Jasmine - Unknown provider: translateFilterProvider <- translateFilter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a unit test that throws me an error :

Unknown provider: translateFilterProvider <- translateFilter

Is this service $translate ? If that's how I can inject it, or you have a solution?

```
import angular from 'angular'
import 'angular-mocks'

let $scope
let $compile
let htmlElement

describe('ProjectGeneralSituationForm', () => {
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('ProjectGeneralSituationModule'))

  beforeEach(() => {
    inject((_$rootScope_, _$compile_) => {
      $scope = _$rootScope_.$new()
      $compile = _$compile_
    })
  })

  beforeEach(() => {
    $scope.project = {}
    $scope.projectTypes = {}
    $scope.projectReferences = {}
    htmlElement = $compile(`<project-general-situation-form project="project" project-types="projectTypes" project-references="projectReferences"></project-general-situation-form>`)($scope)
    $scope.$digest()
  })

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(htmlElement).toBeDefined()
  })
})
```

Comment: is a test of directive?, so  try here inject((_$rootScope_, _$compile_, _$translate_)

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject `$translate` in your controller,

Like this,

```
app.controller("YOUR_CONTROLLER_NAME", function($scope, $translate) {
  // your code goes here
});
```

Hope this helps!